# PDO Transactions. What is the right way to roll back

Tags: php, sql, pdo

This is not a duplicate of another question.

My question is: 
**how i must run transaction and roll it back if i get any error on the way**

Trying to do next: If the first transaction (query) was successful, move on to the second. The second query is executing in cycle to insert all of the images that were selected for download. So, if the first - successful move on the second. If the second somewhere broke down, I want to cancel the first. Help solve this poser, thank you! If you need additional information, something like my class `class connectPDO`, or something else, I shall add.

```
    try{
        $this->_pdo->beginTransaction();

        //first transaction
        $content_query = "INSERT INTO 
           products_content 
          (url, title, content, meta_title, meta_description, meta_keywords)
           VALUES 
          (:url, :title, :content, :meta_title, :meta_description, :meta_keywords)";

            $this->_pdo->prepare($content_query);
            $this->_pdo->bind(':url', $url);
            $this->_pdo->bind(':title', $title);
            $this->_pdo->bind(':content', $content);
            $this->_pdo->bind(':meta_title', $metaTitle);
            $this->_pdo->bind(':meta_description', $metaDescription);
            $this->_pdo->bind(':meta_keywords', $metaKeywords);
            $this->_pdo->execute();
            $last_id = $this->_pdo->lastInsertId();


            $Uploads->setDirectory('products/id_'.$last_id);
            $fileArray = $Uploads->saveFiles($files);

            for($i=0;$i<count($fileArray['full_size']);$i++) {

                    //second++ transaction
                    $file_query = "INSERT INTO products_images 
                     (product_id, full_size, mini_size) 
                    VALUES 
                     (:product_id, :full_size, :mini_size )";

                $this->_pdo->prepare($file_query);
                $this->_pdo->bind(':product_id', $last_id);
                $this->_pdo->bind(':full_size', $fileArray['full_size'][$i]);
                $this->_pdo->bind(':mini_size', $fileArray['mini_size'][$i]);
                $this->_pdo->execute();
            }

            $this->_pdo->commitTransaction();

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->_pdo->rollBackTransaction();
            return $_SESSION['system']['message'] = "SQL Error: ".$e->getMessage();

        }
```

Comment: There is absolutely nothing special in your case and so I fail to see how it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, i realy post a duplicate. Didn`t find that question before